# Quick question: local-to-global spectral sequence

Tags: notation

What does "$\implies$" mean in the following:

$E_2^{p,q} = H^p(\mathcal Ext^q(F,G)) \implies Ext^{p+q}(F,G)$

Could you explain the meaning of the whole thing? (Let's say $F$ and $G$ are sheaves on some $X$)

Comment: It would absurd to do this here. You seem to know this is a spectral sequence. Just look up any reference on the topic (McCleary, Weibel, Vakil, Google search, ...). It will be explained there.

Answer (score 3):

"$\implies$" means "converges to".